# How do I override yammer css in sharepoint web parts?

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

I've worked with css overriding in sharepoint on numerous occasions, but this one seems to be a bit tricky.

I've embedded yammer using a 2 separate web parts:
-using script editor web part with embedded yammer code
-using yammer web part for sharepoint

I'd like to be able to override multiple areas of the CSS, but for now I'm trying to override the background-color presented behind the network name.

This code doesn't appear to work, even if I brake it apart. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated..
.yj-embed-wide .yj-hd h3, .yj-embed-narrow .yj-hd h3 {background-color:red !important}

Comment: It's not recommended that you attempt to override the styling because this isn't a supported scenario at this time. The CSS classes could change over time. If it breaks you'll be completely out of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I found a design menu in the Yammer Network Admin panel that changed the heading background color. The change is reflected within the sharepoint web part or embedded code for the script editor web part.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to activate or subscribe to the Yammer Enterprise Social Network. This will allow you to manage yammer from the office 365 portal. There is a Design menu option that allow you to include a Logo and limited color schemes.